# Django API to create new user

Tags: python, django, api

I'm trying to create user creation API, but I'm not sure if I'm doing this ok because I get something like this: 
[image]

Am, I doing something wrong? Because I doubt this should look like this, this is my code:

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

from .serializer import *


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def user_creation(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: anything wrong with using the built in users in django? By default the admin section of your project will allow you to create new users. Could you be more specific in what your API is trying to do?

Comment: I want to allow new users to create their accounts from page, not in admin panel because to admin panel only admins have access.

Comment: So you need a user register API?

Comment: Yes, I want to create user registration API

Comment: @api_view(['POST','GET'])

Comment: properly indent code in serializer. Meta class should be inside the serializer class

Comment: Oh, sorry in my project Meta class is inside serializer only here when i were copying code, by mistake I moved meta class outside serializer

Answer (score 2):

Like @Mohit Harshan said you need to add:

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
```

to your view.

When you use the Rest Framework explorer, it is by default making a GET request, so it will always get a complaint if that method is not available. However, in this case your POST methods will still work.

Typically for user generated creation, the GET method will return a simple form that the user can fill in and then submit as a POST request, creating the user.

Comment: Thanks for help, but in my case i want ask why my POST method looks like this on photo, POST should work without this GET, I should get username, password and email fields but instead i have Media type and Content fields.I tried with added GET method but still POST method looked same. Or maybe POST method in API should always have this Media and Content fields?

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved, I wanted to know if POST view should look like on photo, and it should, I just need do write in Content field all my model fields by using dictionary

Comment: Rest framework allows for generic views and viewsets, that would make this a lot easier

Comment: Write class based views